# Using cloneNode to repeat div elements in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm generating a form and one section of the form can be repeated based on input from the user, i.e. a button click adds a duplicate form section to enter more information. I'm using cloneNode since the form section contains HTML that I would like "copied". When I click the button once, the section is duplicated. However, when I click the button a second time the content of both the original form and the previously cloned node are then cloned. So rather than adding one new section, two new sections are added. A third button click adds four new sections. The code for the Polymer element is below:

```
<dom-module id="services-block">
<template>
<style>
    .horizontal-section {
        min-width: 130px;
    }
    paper-button {
        margin-bottom: 24px;
    }
    paper-button.colorful {
        color: #4285f4;
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>
<div id="myDiv">
    <h3>Services</h3>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <paper-input name="@context" hidden value="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Network-of-BioThings/smartAPI/master/schema/smartAPI.api.jsonld"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="service-name" label="* Name" required type="string"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="service-description" label="Description" type="string"></paper-input>

         <p>HTTP Method</p>
         <input list="httpMethod" name="HTTP Method" label="HM Test">
         <datalist id="httpMethod">
            <option value="GET">
            <option value="PUT">
            <option value="POST">
            <option value="DELETE">
        </datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
<paper-button class="colorful" raised on-click="repeatDiv">Add</paper-button>
<paper-button class="colorful" raised on-click="deleteDiv">Remove</paper-button>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "services-block",
    repeatDiv: function() {
        console.log("** Add services block")
        var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        clone = div.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "some_id";
        document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(clone);
    }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the clone as a child of myDiv, so when you duplicate myDiv the 2nd time, you're duplicating it and it's children. Probably need to change to

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").parentNode.appendChild(clone);
```